# Update Created_at timestamp Laravel db seeding

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm running an app that processes user data entered over a period of time.  For that, I need to change the timestamps in the data I use to seed the database.  I have a nice loop to do it, but the problem is, when I run the database seeding, nothing happens.  I'm wondering if there is a Laravel specific thing that prevents this, and if so how to get around it.

```
            $record->created_at = $fakeCreateDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $record->save();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, created_at and updated_at are "special". Laravel sets the timestamp for created_at at create time and updated_at at update time.

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#timestamps

You can turn them off by doing this inside your model

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

> By default, Eloquent will maintain the created_at and updated_at columns on your database table automatically. Simply add these
>   timestamp columns to your table and Eloquent will take care of the
>   rest. If you do not wish for Eloquent to maintain these columns, add
>   the following property to your model
>
> Once a model is defined, you are ready to start retrieving and
>   creating records in your table. Note that you will need to place
>   updated_at and created_at columns on your table by default. If you do
>   not wish to have these columns automatically maintained, set the
>   $timestamps property on your model to false.

Comment: Brilliant!  I just added that one line of code to my model, and still left the `$table->timestamps();` in my migration builder and it worked just as it should.

Answer (score 2):

The `Carbon::now()`  method can help you here.

In your example, it should work with

```
$record->created_at = \Carbon\Carbon::now()
$record->save()
```

If you need to do an insert with `DB::table`, for example to update the date, you need to use the right method to create the date.

Let's say you have a table `things` with only `id` and `timestamps` like this Schema

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->timestamps();
```

One example of a date update is:

```
DB::table('things')->insert(['created_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()]);
```